# Drupal 8 twig date field outputting today's date instead of the field's date

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

I'm editing a Drupal 8 Twig file in order to output a certain date field named field_datum. I've used the official Drupal documentation in order to do this. However, my code outputs today's date instead of the actual date value of the field.

I've set the date up to be outputted in a Date format that I've added in Drupal, named 'date_only'.

The code:

```
{% if content.field_datum %}
        <div {{ content_attributes.addClass('teaser__datum') }}> <span style="font-weight: bold;">{{content.field_datum|field_label}}:</span> {{content.field_datum.value|date('U')|format_date('date_only') }} </div>
      {% endif %}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how I can alter the code to show the actual field's value instead of today's date?

Comment: You have two date formatters in place, remove `|format_date('date_only')`. Right now it takes the result of `date('U')` which is today and turns it into "date_only" format.

Comment: @Paul you are mistaken, `| date('U')` transforms any (valid) datetime notation into its representative unix timestamp and not just into `today`. See [here](https://twigfiddle.com/4n0kwt)

Comment: The pipe in front is important, `date('U')` by itself will return the timestamp of right now. With the pipe it will of course take the value in front of the pipe as argument.

Comment: @Paul not sure your comments made sense, the pipelines are already there.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to use node.field_datum instead of content.field_datum